# iOS Swift How to record Video with mp3 Music and NO Microphone

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avcapturedevice

I am trying to record video from an iOS app along with a pre-recored audio file.  I have seen this done in many apps like TikTok, Instagram, etc.

I am able to successfully record the video and using media player allowing the user to select the audio file.

I can even play the audio and record video, BUT, how do I disable the microphone?  I do not want audio from the mic, just from the sound file.

I am adding the audio input device like so:

```
        let audioInputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)
    if captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput)
    {
        captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
    }
```

Comment: Could please tell, What are you used to record video? Please add some more code.

Comment: I have re-posted this with more code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927318/ios-record-video-with-audio-from-a-file